# How to use autocomplete in saltstack

Tags: autocomplete, salt-stack

I want to use bash autocomplete feature with saltstack.

`salt '*' test.p <tab>` should complete the word and make it `salt '*' test.ping`.

After googling, I got the following links:
[salt.bash](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/pkg/salt.bash)
& [CLI completion](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/execution/remote_execution.html#cli-completion)

However, I cannot figure out how to use it. Autocompletion feature is not working by default. Please provide any step by step guide to activate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download the `salt.bash` file.

   ```
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saltstack/salt/develop/pkg/salt.bash
   ```
2. Copy the file to /etc/bash_completion.d/

   ```
    cp salt.bash /etc/bash_completion.d/
   ```
3. Logout and logback in. or source the file

   ```
    source /etc/bash_completion.d/salt.bash
   ```
4. Now use salt auto-completion feature

   ```
    salt '*' tes[[tab]].pi[[tab]]
   ```

   and get the result:

   ```
    salt '*' test.ping
   ```